# Vim-SyntaxHighlight: Custom Syntax Highlighting With Vim

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to make my own syntax highlighting for vim. I was following the instructions in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/844004/creating-a-simple-vim-syntax-highlighting) (first answer) but I need to set a group for import and pack, and another group for func, lib, group. How can I do this?

I'm using vim on osx Yosemite.

Comment: You seem to be missing a link in the question

Comment: Have you looked at the `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim` (or any other syntax file in the folder)? There are a lot of examples in there.

Comment: This should be fairly simple if you look at a tutorial on it.  I honestly don't see a question here.  If you want to learn how to accomplish the syntax grouping of the things you listed, you might want to take a look at chapters 45 through 47 of http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/

Comment: @DCPY Try to make a syntax file first, starting with just a single highlight. If you run into problems, you're of course welcome to ask one (or more!) question(s) about it. Post the code that you've tried so far, explain what exactly what you want to do, and what doesn't work.